# How to append multiple files with addtional information to a form data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to append multiple text and field fields to form data. The good thing is that I can successfully send the form data to my backend by postman (see picture below) .

**The Problem:**

The problem is that in my react js frontend I am not able to create the form data in such a way that my backend understands. With the following code my backend tells me that `story_media(pin):['This field is required.']`.

```
onClickUpload (e){

  let files = this.state.image;

  //  files is a array in the following structure
  // 0: {isTitlePicture: true, file: File}
  // 1: {isTitlePicture: false, file: File}
  // 2: {isTitlePicture: false, file: File}
  // 3: {isTitlePicture: false, file: File}

  var data = new FormData();
  data.append('title', this.state.title);

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    data.append('story_media[]', files[i])
 }

   this.props.addStory(data);

}
```

([image: see picture])

Postman Configuration

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('title', 'Neuer Test');
data.append('story_media[0]isTitlePicture', 'True');
data.append('story_media[0]file', fs.createReadStream('/C:/4.jpeg'));

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/story/createupdatedestroy/',
  headers: { 
    'Authorization': 'Token 12345', 
    ...data.getHeaders()
  },
  data : data
};
```

What do i wrong with constructing the form data?

I am happy for any clarification.

Comment: by form data, do you mean JSON data? because a form data can be anything

Comment: @AKC i have actually not futher specified if it is JSON. See also the header of my postman post that I added.